# Save file in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I recoreded a macro of me saving a file, but I want the name of the file to be

"OOR" & " " & Date & " " & Time

so the output should be OOR 10.18.2017 07:38 AM

Can someone help me with the code? Greatly apreciate it:

```
 ChDir "C:\Users\spall1\Desktop\Base Business\Base Business Report\OOR Report"
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
     "C:\Users\spall1\Desktop\Base Business\Base Business Report\OOR Report\OOR & DATE & TIME.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: You cannot use a colon in a filename.

Comment: I just clicked record and thats the code that came up, i just changed the part towards the end where it says OOR & DATE & TIME

The macro seems to be working but it saves the file name as OOR DATE TIME instead of OOR 10/18/2017 07:53 AM

Comment: The colon character (`:`) is not valid in the name of a file or folder (at least on windows), so you'd need to replace that by something else.

Comment: If you are putting date and time in a file name then best to use ISO-like format with 24hr clock, for example OOR 2017-10-18 0753 - non-ambiguous, sorts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the constant String part with `"` before adding the variable of `Date` and `Time`.

Change the last part of the string from:

```
\OOR & DATE & TIME.xlsx"
```

to:

```
\OOR" & Date & Time & ".xlsx"
```

**Or**, you could use VBA `Now`, which will give you both `Date` and `Time`:

```
\OOR" & Now & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: I used the Now method, and its still giving me a bug :( 

it says it can not find the file name

Answer (score -2):

```
:
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
     Filename:= _
      "C:\Users\spall1\Desktop\Base Business\Base Business Report\OOR Report\OOR " & Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD HHMM") & ".xls" _
     , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook _
     , CreateBackup:=False
:
```